# why is less<T> comparator used for max heap and greater<T> for min heap?

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

Shouldn't it be the opposite?
what do we mean by less and greater in detail when we use them as comparators
I don't understand the complete explanation for this, could someone please help me out.

Comment: You know that these two comparators are interchangeable, up to arguments order, don't you?

Comment: I am 5 years older than my brother, he claims to be 5 years younger than me. Who is right?

Comment: It's convenient because you only need to implement `<` for your type to work with ordered library collections in their default order.

Answer (score 1):

It is purley a matter of convention to use the comparator to decide whether one element `a` comes **before** another element `b`. Thats why for increasing order `a < b` or `std::less` is used and for decreasing order `a > b` / `std::greater`.

If the convention was the opposite: Use the comparater to decide which element comes last. Then `<` would result in decreasing order and `>` would result in increasing order.